# CSV lookup using two CSV files and producing new file

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am extremely new to the world of python and I have a problem I don't know how to face. Examples of the tables I am concerned with are found in the following link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm1it.png

I have a csv file containing a table similar to that in t1 (from the link), acting as a database (this is just a snippet of the database as a whole).

I have another table (t2), which I want to act as my search parameters.

I want to create a lookup and return program that will use t2 as a means of looking through t1 and providing me with an output csv file which provides me with all of the A parameters along with replacing the ions in species_a, species_b and species_c with numeric values assigned to them in t2. And if there is no value in species_c then it should return as a -1. The final table would look similar to this: t3.

The reason for this convoluted method of doing things is that I have accumulated a database that is in a format different to a piece of software I am using. I won't be able to simply change the database ions to those of the numbers in t2 as the allocation of the numbers vairies based on the material I am considering in my system each time I start a new run with my software.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the pandas library in my opinion.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table

There are more concise ways of doing this (you can create a dictionary and remap the values in the columns to be the ID instead), but to your question seemed to be about joining the data, so here is an example of how pandas can join .csv files:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('../path/t1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('../path/t2.csv')

combined = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='species_a', right_on='aq_species')

combined = pd.merge(combined, df2, how='left', left_on='species_b', right_on='aq_species')

combined = pd.merge(combined, df3, how='left', left_on='species_c', right_on='aq_species')

#this will output 3 ion_id columns which you can then rename

combined.rename(columns={'ion_id' : 'species_a_id', 'ion_id_x' : 'species_b_id', 'ion_id_y' : 'species_c_id'}, inplace=True)

combined.to_csv('../path/t3.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I've tried this but receive a - `KeyError: 'aq_species'`

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I don't have your CSV files. The csv module is your friend.

```
import sys
import csv

# Create a map of species to ion ID
species_map = {}
with open('t2.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        species_map[row[1]] = row[0]

# Write the output mapping species names to IDs
fieldnames = ['species_a', 'species_b', 'species_c', 'A0',  'A1',  'A2',  'A3',  'A4',  'A5', 'interaction_type']
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
with open('t1.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        row['species_a'] = species_map.get(row['species_a'], -1)
        row['species_b'] = species_map.get(row['species_b'], -1)
        row['species_c'] = species_map.get(row['species_c'], -1)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi attempted using this code and for the most part it appears to have done quite well. However, it has replaced all of the values in t1, when I wanted to just get a selection of values from the database. It is definitely a useful method for projects in the future though. I have provided the code for how I did it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this problem out myself with arguably a much longer piece of code:

```
import csv
import itertools
from itertools import izip

def all_species_combination():
        'Creates all possible ion combinations so that they can compare against the database'
        with open('t2', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            # to replace empty spacies within list entries
            global combined
            text = []
            species_a = []
            species_b = []
            species_c = []
            combined = []
            # obtaining three lists of the aqueous species so that they can be combined later
            for row in reader:
                species_a.append(row[1])
                species_b.append(row[1])
                species_c.append(row[1])


            # Iteratively combines the three separate species lists to provide a combined list
            list(itertools.product(species_a, species_b, species_c))
            for x in itertools.product(species_a, species_b, species_c):
                combined.append(x)

def lookup_ion_combos():
        'Checks the database csv file whether potential database entries are available'
        with open('t1', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            global species_lookup
            species_lookup = []
            pitzer_id = []
            species_a = []
            species_b = []
            species_c = []

            for row in combined:
                species_a.append(row[0])
                species_b.append(row[1])
                species_c.append(row[2])
            # Iteratively goes through every row of ion combinations and compares to t1.
            for row in reader:
                for i in range(len(species_a)):
                    if row[0] == species_a[i]:
                        if row[1] == species_b[i]: 
                                if row[2] == species_c[i]: 
                                        species_lookup.append(row[0:11])
def gems_ions():
'Creates dictionary of t2 to replace corresponding species'
with open(‘t2.csv’, 'rb') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(g)
    global ion_id, atom, dictionary, zero_dict
    ion_id = []
    atom = []

    for row in reader:
        ion_id.append(row[0])
        atom.append(row[1])

    ion_id = [w.replace(' ','').replace('@','') for w in ion_id]
    atom = [w.replace(' ','').replace('@','') for w in atom]

    dictionary = dict(zip(atom, ion_id))

DATA = {"records": [dictionary]}
for name, datalist in DATA.iteritems():  # Or items() in Python 3.x
    for datadict in datalist:
        for key, value in datadict.items():
            if value == '0':
                datadict[key] = 'zero'

zero_dict = {'zero':'0'}

all_species_combination()
lookup_ion_combos()
gems_ions()
```

This allowed me to produce a new array with all the looked up ions linked to their respective values. I then created a dictionary to convert them into numerical values based on t2.

Thanks for trying to help!